# Custom button with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, cordova

I am working on a phonegap. I have made a kind of "custom button", which is actually just a `<div>` with an `ng-click` attached to it.

However, I am encountering 2 problems:

1. How do I give the user a feedback on his touch event? Buttons have a sort of default wired up animation. How would I add a "highlight" animation on div touch?
2. ng-disabled doesn't seem to stop the user from activating the `ng-click` event wired up to the button. - Solved!

here is the code for a sample button:

```
<div class="app-button center" ng-click="contactEmployee('email')" ng-disabled="buttonDisabled"> 
    <div class="absolute">
        <p class="absolute app-button-title-text">title</p>
        <div class="app-button-icon-container absolute">
            <img src="img/envelope-icon.png" class="absolute app-button-icon">
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: ng-click works on any element, even text.

Comment: ng-click works.My problem is disabling it when ng-disabled=true

Comment: Yeah, then you need to add extra logic. See [this](http://baudehlo.com/2014/02/24/angular-js-ng-click-still-fires-when-div-is-ngdisabled/)

Comment: Sorry for the abundance of comments, but it's also interesting to note that there is no disabled state for divs. That's probably the reason why it's still firing.

Comment: Its ok! the article you pointed me too helped me a lot.